# Crystal reports are displaying blank after deploying it in IIS

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, iis-7.5, crystal-reports-2008

Crystal report is working fine in local. But when i deployed it in IIS, its displaying a blank page. I have tried the following one. But this is not working for me.

"Downloading and installing runtime for Crystal Reports 13 for Visual Studio 2010. (You might want to skip this step if you already did this before and your application is working locally).

"Once the runtime is installed. Crystal Reports will install the required support files in the location of your local computer: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13

Copy the entire Crystal Report Support folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13 to your Website's SITE_ROOT\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 folder.

4) If you do not have a \aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319 folders in your website's root. Please create them manually and then copy the crystalreportviewers13 into it."

Please give me a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the whole report is blank? or is adding a blank page at the end?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that make sure your report files are being published when you publish your project with the option 'Only files needed to run this application'. [This](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx) resource might help

Answer (score 0):

*I have faced the same problem and resolved it by following these these steps:*

At first, you have to debug your application javascript, let us say on Chrome (I prefer chrome debugging tool). It will show you exactly what errors your crystal report is generating.

In my case, my Jquery.js library had to be included before bootstrap.js library like this:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/npm.js"></script>
```

Secondly, the report was unable to connect to my ODBC driver to load data, that was because of ODBC permission problem. Again I had to fix this one.
These errors were all shown in the debugging console, so concentrate on it.